# qgraph: how to fix node positions when changing graph type?

Tags: r, nodes, edges, network-analysis

In qgraph, you can calculate the edge weights in several ways. For this example, I'll use cor (raw correlations) and pcor (partial correlations).

Notice that the node positions change between graphs:

```
library(qgraph)
qgraph(cor(iris[, -5]),
       layout = "spring",
       labels = colnames(iris[, -5]),
       legend = F,
       graph = "cor")
```

[image: resulting correlation network]

```
qgraph(cor(iris[, -5]),
       layout = "spring",
       labels = colnames(iris[, -5]),
       legend = F,
       graph = "pcor")
```

[image: resulting partial correlation network]

In this case, I'd like to compare edges, but that's much harder to do when you have to find the edge because it moved. Is there a way fix the positions of the nodes and edges so that you get two identical graphs, with the only change being edge width?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why, but using the argument `layout = "groups"` did the trick:

```
qgraph(cor(iris[, -5]),
       layout = "groups",
       labels = colnames(iris[, -5]),
       legend = F,
       graph = "cor")
qgraph(cor(iris[, -5]),
       layout = "groups",
       labels = colnames(iris[, -5]),
       legend = F,
       graph = "pcor")
```